# MxGraph : how to collapse given cell on click (javascript)

Tags: mxgraph

I want to collapse a cell of MxGraph and it's children when clicked on an overlay

```html
        overlay2.addListener(mxEvent.CLICK, function (sender, evt3) {
          console.log("evt3", evt3)
          setVertexStatus(null);
          var cell = evt3.getProperty("cell");
//this is the cell and it's children I need to collapse
})
```

any answer with example will help

Answer (score 0):

Eventually figured out the solution.

created a function

```
function collapseSubtree(graph, cell, shouldCollapse) {
    // Gets the subtree from cell downwards
    var cells = [];
    var i = 0;
    graph.traverse(cell, true, function (vertex) {
      console.log("cells", cells, cells.length);
      if(i == 0){
        cells.push(vertex);
      }else{
        cells.push(vertex);
      }
      i++;
      return true;
    });
    graph.foldCells(shouldCollapse, true, cells);
  }
```

called this function form onClick event of the overlay

```
collapseSubtree(graph, cell, true);
```

This can be used to expand or collapse